# Проверьте правильность расстановки знаков препинания

Tags: грамматика

Рядом с ним – уличный рынок, на котором можно купить монеты, и сувениры, в частности всевозможные статуэтки, начиная от крошечных – с наперсток, и заканчивая гигантами с человеческий рост.

Answer (score 1):

*Рядом с ним – уличный рынок, на котором можно купить монеты и сувениры, в частности всевозможные статуэтки, начиная от крошечных, с наперсток, и заканчивая гигантами с человеческий рост.*

Монеты от сувениров нет причин отделять запятой; уточнение "с напёрсток" или в двух тире, или в запятых, но три тире на недлинное предложение как бы много, потому выбираю запятые.

Comment: Спасибо. А "в частности" и "заканчивая" - не нужно выделять запятыми?

Comment: Ни за что! У Вас указано *что* конкретно подразумевает эта "частность" (статуэтки) и чем заканчивая - гигантами.